# Python print floats padded with spaces instead of zeros

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a float `myfloat = 0.002` I want to print with space padding `' '` instead of trailing zeros.

Let's say I want to print `myfloat` with space-padding right-justified to 5 spaces. For clarity I will print `'|'` after my float.

What I want:
`0.002  |`

What padded printing (I know of) gives:

```
>>> print(str(myfloat) + '|') # no padding, formatting
0.002|
>>> print('%.5f' % myfloat + '|') 
0.00200|
>>> print('{0:<5f}|'.format(myfloat))
0.002000|
>>> print('{0:.5f}|'.format(myfloat)) 
0.00200|
```

I know `print('{0:<Xf}|'.format(myfloat))` pads with spaces after X > 8 or so. I do not want any trailing zeros.

I am printing multiple floats on the same line. They have varying string lengths and I want them evenly justified with space padding rather than zeros, so a static padding string will not work.

For instance, lets say I want to print the contents of `myfloatlist1 = [0.01, 0.002, 0.0003, 0.00004]` and `myfloatlist2 = [0.00004, 0.0003, 0.002, 0.01]`on a two lines, each with the same spaced padding:

```
0.01     0.002    0.0003   0.00004 
0.00004  0.0003   0.002    0.01
```

Is there anyway to pad float prints with spaces (without converting the float to a string or something)?

Comment: have you tried `zfill` in python ??

Comment: @warl0ck "string.zfill(s, width): Pad a numeric string s on the left **with zero digits** until the given width is reached. Strings starting with a sign are handled correctly." I am not looking for zero padding.

Comment: You may want to have a look at module prettytable or PTable on pypi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this?

```
>>> '{0: <8}|'.format(str(myfloat))
'0.002   |'
```

Edit: following Gall's comment, this suffices

```
>>> '{0: <8}|'.format(myfloat)
'0.002   |'
```

Comment: This feels like the right way to go. The ``str`` call is not needed though.

Comment: Nice. Didn't realize the float conversion flag `f` was affecting the padding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

print(str(myfloat).ljust(6, ' ') + '|')

If you need more white spaces just change 6 to whatever you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do

```
myfloat = 0.002
pads = ' '*4 # 4 is the number of trailing spaces I am adding. Change accordingly
marker = '|'
print(str(myfloat)+pads+marker) #0.002    |
```

Comment: I do not think a static padding variable will work here :[